# Changing Environment Reverb of SceneKit in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, scenekit, scnaudioplayer

I'm trying to get 3d audio effects using SceneKit in Swift.

My scene.rootNode is a box geometry with 100x100x100 dimension. Inside scene.rootNode, I have a boxNode with 50x5050 dimension. Then inside the boxNode, I have audioNode generating sound with 1x1x1 dimension as well as cameraNode with 1x1x1 dimension. The position audioNode is 0,0,0, and the position of cameraNode is 0,0,-10.

In order to give deeper sense of spatial perception, I would like to put a reverb. However, I can't access SCNView.AVAudioEnvironmentNode.

It compiles but environment results in nil and crash.

```
let environment = sceneView.audioEnvironmentNode
environment.reverbBlend = 0.5 // CRASH!: LLBD
environment.renderingAlgorithm = .HRTFHQ
let reverb = environment.reverbParameters
reverb.enable = true
reverb.loadFactoryReverbPreset(.mediumRoom)
```

I also tried making my own AVAudioEnvironment, enabling reverb, and then assigning to sceneView.audioEnvironmentNode, but XCode says sceneView.audioEnvironmentNode is immutable.

I'd appreciate if someone could help me to put reverb on my scene.

Here's my testing code. Thanks!

```
import Cocoa
import AVFoundation
import SceneKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var sceneView: SCNView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Sounds/Test_mono.mp3", ofType: nil)
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
        let source = SCNAudioSource(url: url)!
        source.loops = true
        source.shouldStream = false
        source.isPositional = true
        source.load()
        let player = SCNAudioPlayer(source: source)
        if let apn = player.audioNode as? AVAudioPlayerNode {
            apn.renderingAlgorithm = .HRTFHQ
            apn.reverbBlend = 0.5
        }

        let audioNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width:1, height:1, length:1, chamferRadius: 0.1))
        let cameraNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width:1, height:1, length:1, chamferRadius: 0.1))
cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width:50, height:50, length:50, chamferRadius: 1))
        boxNode.addChildNode(audioNode)
        audioNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
        boxNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -10)

        let scene = SCNScene()
        scene.rootNode.geometry = SCNBox(width:100, height:100, length:100, chamferRadius: 0.1)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
        boxNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)

        sceneView.scene = scene
        sceneView.pointOfView = cameraNode
        sceneView.audioListener = cameraNode
        let environment = sceneView.audioEnvironmentNode
        environment.reverbBlend = 0.5 // CRASH!: LLBD
        environment.renderingAlgorithm = .HRTF
        let reverb = environment.reverbParameters
        reverb.enable = true
        reverb.loadFactoryReverbPreset(.mediumRoom)

        audioNode.addAudioPlayer(player)
        let move = SCNAction.moveBy(x:0, y:1, z:0, duration: 1)
        let sequence = SCNAction.sequence([move])
        let loop = SCNAction.repeatForever(sequence)
        audioNode.runAction(loop)


// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the first snippet, you cannot write to a read-only. The [`audioEnvironmentNode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1523582-audioenvironmentnode) is a read-only property that is used to spatialize the audio from the `SCNPlayer` that's been added to the scene.

Looking through the second (longer) snippet, you are creating two nodes and applying reverb but those nodes are never added to the scene.

According to the [Apple Docs for SCNPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnaudioplayer)

> An SCNAudioPlayer object controls playback of a positional audio source in a SceneKit scene. To use positional audio, first create a reusable SCNAudioSource or AVAudioNode object to provide an audio stream. Then, create an audio player to control the playback of that audio source. Finally, attach the audio player to an SCNNode object for spatialized 3D audio playback based on the position of that node relative to the scene’s audioListener node.

If you look at your code, even though you have created the `player : SCNPlayer` and add reverb through casting to `apn = player.audioNode as? AVAudioPlayerNode` at no point in your code are you attaching either node to a SCNNode that is in scene.

I would recommend you add the `apn` as a child to a node and add it to the scene.

If you have already done this but are still running into issues, please update your snippet above.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually I did add the player to a node toward the end. "audioNode.addAudioPlayer(player)". Otherwise, I would not have heard any sound. Also audioNode is added to a box, and box is added to a sceneView.rootNode.